# Converting BYTE* from MODULEENTRY32's modBaseAddr to a std::string

Tags: c++, winapi

I've filled a `MODULEENTRY32` struct from winapi including the `modBaseAddr`.  I need to convert it to a `std::string` while keeping its format.  I've tried copying the `BYTE *modBaseAddr` contents to a `char` buffer then making a `std::string` out of that.  This generated some cryptic characters, and other times gave a mem access violation: `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x001013C0.`.  I understand why this happens, and after further research I'm stumped on any solutions.

Thanks,

Edit:  To clarify my intent, I'm logging it solely for the memory address

Comment: Why do you need the `modBaseAddr` in a `string`? It is a pointer to the module within its parent process. What could it possibly serve to put the raw bytes being pointed at, or even of the pointer itself, into a `string`? Other than maybe for visual display/logging, in which case you should format the numeric value of the pointer into a hex string, rather than the bytes that the pointer points to. What are you really trying to accomplish with the `modBaseAddr` exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: It's for logging purposes, I edited my post to be more specific, thank you.  I mistakenly was trying to format the raw bytes into a string, thinking the value held at the pointed address was the module's base address.  I'll give your suggestion a shot!

Comment: Your edit doesn't really clarify anything. `modBaseAddr` is a pointer, are you trying to log just the memory address itself that the pointer holds, or are you trying to log the module data that is located at the memory address being pointed to?

Comment: Thanks again, logging just for the memory address that the pointer holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `std::ostringstream`.  Any kind of pointer that is passed to `operator<<`, other than a `char*`, will print out the address it holds when.  `char*` is handled special as a null-terminated string instead.  Since `BYTE*` is really a `char*`, you just have to type-cast it to print its address:

```
std::ostringstream o;
o << (void*) modBaseAddr;
std::string str = o.str();
```

Comment: "*`BYTE*` is really a `char*`*" = more accurately, it is actually an `unsigned char*`, not a `char*`.  But, `operator<<` treats `char*`, `signed char*` and `unsigned char*` as null-terminated strings, so the end result is the same either way.